Single bundle file using ESBUILD
I have created a new project which consist on a web-component created with angular-elements. I'm using angular 17 and the new default builder '@angular-devkit/build-angular:application'.
As this web component will be used in non-angular apps, I would like to have a single bundle file containing all the required code. I know people uses the ngx-build-plus compiler in order to configure webpack and do this, but is there any possibility to do this with the new compiler?"
I have already tested importing all the files from the build into a static html file, and it currently works.
But im expecting to be able to merge all of this files into a single one.

I have ended up using rollup to solve this problem, also because I wanted to include styles and assets in the same bundle.
My rollup config looks something like this:
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import multiEntry from '@rollup/plugin-multi-entry';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default {
  input: [
    'dist/my-angular-app/browser/*.js',
  ],
  output: {
    file: 'dist/single/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'MyWebComponent',
    sourcemap: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    multiEntry(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    postcss({
      inject: true,
      extract: true,
      minimize: true,
    }),
    babel({
      babelHelpers: 'bundled',
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      compact: true,
    }),
    terser(),
  ]
};

Hope that this helps someone else.

Recently struggled with a similar requirement.
Tried the last comment on this post: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/1cstcc0/single_bundle_file_using_esbuild/
const folder = 'dist/browser/';
const fs = require('fs');
let content = 'import "' + folder + 'polyfills.js";\n';
fs.readdirSync(folder).forEach((file) => {
  if (file.substring(file.length - 3) === '.js' && file !== 'polyfills.js') {
    content += 'import "' + folder + file + '";\n';
  }
});
fs.writeFile(folder + 'bundle.ts', content, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('file written successfully');
  }
});

And keep in mind to use outputHashing: none and then executing:
esbuild dist/browser/bundle.ts --bundle --minify --outdir=dist/browser

The resulting bundle contains the whole Angular application so you can import it in your index.html
Just beware you might have to do some minor adjustments, but it works.

I had problems with a similar solution, as I'm using an external library which is already a minified bundle. Instead of that, I have ended up using rollup to bundle as a single file (including the css and assets).
